# What damage does a Halfling's Staff Sling deal?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage, creature-size, halfling

I'm about to play a Halfling in my 1st Pathfinder game and I'm a bit confused about the Halflings Staff Sling.

### Relevant information

Under "Standard Racial Traits" for halflings it states:

> **Size:** Halflings are Small creatures

In the rules weapon size is described as follows:

> **Weapon Size:** Every weapon has a size category. This designation
>   indicates the size of the creature for which the weapon was designed.
>   A weapon's size category isn't the same as its size as an object.
>   Instead, a weapon's size category is keyed to the size of the intended
>   wielder. In general, a light weapon is an object two size categories
>   smaller than the wielder...

Also in the rules "Dmg" is described as follows:

> **Dmg:** These columns give the damage dealt by the weapon on a successful
>   hit. The column labeled “Dmg (S)” is for Small weapons. The column
>   labeled “Dmg (M)” is for Medium weapons.

Under "Simple Weapons" the "Sling" is listed as follows:

> **Sling:** Dmg (S) 1d3 or DMG (M) 1d4, x2 Critical, 50' Range

Under "Exotic Weapons" the "Staff Sling, Halfling" is listed as follows:

> **Staff Sling, Halfling:** Dmg (S) 1d6 or Dmg (M) 1d8, x3 Critical, 80' Range

### My questions

Does the bullet shot from a "Staff Sling, Halfling" do 1d6 or 1d8 in damage or is that considered the damage done using the staff sling as a blunt weapon, and the actual bullet dmg is the dmg listed under "Sling"?

Also, if the staff sling is made for a Halfling, and a Halfling is "Small", why is there something listed under "Dmg (M)"?

Comment: Hi @BryGuy. I've removed the dagger question from your question - please ask it separately. It's a very different question, and multiple disparate questions shouldn't be asked together. You don't have a limited budget of questions, so it's fine to ask it separately. I've left the two staff sling questions in here since the second is related enough (but I'm not sure about that) - but I've put your main question first and foremost.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**A bullet shot from a small-sized Staff Sling deals 1d6**

Just as the table indicates, using the weapon in this fashion deals 1d6 points of damage.

**The Medium is for other users and corner cases**

For example, if you cast Enlarge Person on the halfling, that damage value becomes relevant. A human who masters the Staff Sling would use a medium one as well.

Comment: Can the staff sling be used as a melee weapon? @BryGuy seems to suggest that the 1d6 (or 1d8) might be for using it as a staff, i.e. as a melee weapon; is that even an option? Quoting the staff sling’s description text would improve this answer, I think.

Comment: Found this in the item description: "A halfling sling staff can be used as a simple weapon that deals bludgeoning damage equal to that of a club of its size."  A small club is 1d4.

Comment: @KRyan it might help to get an idea of what a staff sling is - a [picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Friezen_vallen_de_toren_van_Damiate_aan.jpg) (the two guys in the back of the boat have staff slings) and the associated [wiki article on sling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sling_(weapon)#Staff_sling).

Answer (score 0):

If you use a bullet for small staff slings it deals 1d6 points of damage and you add your strength modifier. But if you use ordinary rocks for a small staff sling its damage would be 1d4 because that is the damage for a tiny sling staff.

The medium damage for staff slings are for medium characters who uses staff slings.